# how many custom options a product can have

Tags: custom-options

I am creating a configurable product, i need to add some 52 custom options to that product.

But i am unable to add 23rd option. 22 options and their values are created fine but as soon as I start to create 23rd custom option and save product. It gives message "The product is saved." but 23rd custom option is not there.

EDIT--

I have mix of text, area, checkboxes and radio buttons as product options. I can add text or area as another product option but cannot add another checkbox type. There are already 5 checkboxes types of product options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your PHP settings and test to increase `max_input_vars`.

For `php.ini`

```
max_input_vars = 10000
```

For `.htaccess`

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

For `suhosin` also add

```
suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000
```

Comment: max_input_vars seems to have correct value and i dont see any issue with that. Can you please check my EDITED question?

Comment: What do you mean with "correct" value? (Try to increase) I just testet to add 10 checkboxes and it worked ....

Answer (score -1):

Custom options don't make a product configurable, these are simply options for a simple product. Configurable product is a set of simple products so you create simple products e.g. Shirt Size S, Shirt Size M, and Shirt size L which all have their own prices which could be same or different and quantity etc. Now a configurable product will hold these products and let end user select sizes. There are certain conditions for creating a configurable product like the attribute that you're creating config product on should be global further read here http://bit.ly/2sMhkvi

Now how many custom options can you add to a simple product is a subjective question, technically as many as you need but obviously you don't want to add 100's because that will be very bad UI. Why your options aren't showing after a certain number could be because of your server resources e.g. php memory issue.

Comment: thank you for explaining the difference. i luckily know this difference and wanted to work with configurable product having product options.

Comment: check memory_limit value in your php.ini file, if possible increase it to 256 or 512M. If that doesn't work increase values of max_execution_time to  3000 and similarly increase values of max_input_time and max_input_vars